DataTable doesn't work perfectly, showing table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error
I was perfectly implement dataTable in my laravel project.For this i followed some tutorial data doesn't show but again and again showing "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see https://datatables.net/tn/7". I dont understand how to fix this.
In the console following error showing

Could you tell me where is my problem.
My Controller Code
use App\Models\Totalmember;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;

 public function totalviewmembers(Request $request)
     {
         if ($request->ajax()) {
             $data = Totalmember::select('membername', 'cellnumber', 'branchname', 'presentaddress', 'uniqueid');
             //echo $data;
             return DataTables::of($data)
                 ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                     return '<a href="'.url('edit/'.$row->uniqueid).'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>';
                 })
                 ->rawColumns(['action'])
                 ->make(true);
         }
     
         // Load the view
         return view('admin.totalmember.viewtotalmembers');
     }

Route
Route::get('/viewmember', [TotalmembersController::class, 'totalviewmembers']);

This is my blade coding
<table class="table table-bordered data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Branch Name</th>
            <th>Present Address</th>
            <th style="display: none;">Unique ID</th> <!-- Hidden -->
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ url('totalviewmembers') }}", // AJAX Route
            columns: [
                {data: 'membername', name: 'membername'},
                {data: 'cellnumber', name: 'cellnumber'},
                {data: 'branchname', name: 'branchname'},
                {data: 'presentaddress', name: 'presentaddress'},
                {
                    data: 'uniqueid', 
                    name: 'uniqueid',
                    visible: false, // Hidden column
                    searchable: true // Used for search functionality
                },
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ]
        });
    });
</script>


You set the wrong route
Change to this
ajax: "{{ url('viewmember') }}",

If you still want to stick on your old name, you can name that route e.g
Route::get('/viewmember', [TotalmembersController::class, 'totalviewmembers'])->name('totalviewmembers');;


After adding the route,  have you clear the route cache?
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear


I have to did many times

Could you please check that route into the route list by command:
php artisan route:list

I have experienced this when the columns display in  are not the same with  data
or, you can try :

Check route
Clear route, cache, & config

php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear


in this situation it's working. when i add multiple hidden column then same error is occur.any one can tell me.
    <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>Branch Name</th>
                <th>Present Address</th>
                <th style="display: none;">Unique ID</th> 
                <th style="display: none;">Father Name</th> 
                <th style="display: none;">Mother Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ url('viewmember') }}", // AJAX Route
                columns: [
                    {data: 'membername', name: 'membername'},
                    {data: 'cellnumber', name: 'cellnumber'},
                    {data: 'branchname', name: 'branchname'},
                    {data: 'presentaddress', name: 'presentaddress'},
                    {
                        data: 'uniqueid', 
                        name: 'uniqueid',
                        visible: false, 
                        searchable: true // Used for search functionality
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'fathername', 
                        name: 'fathername',
                        visible: false, // Hidden column
                        searchable: true // Used for search functionality
                    },
    
                    {
                        data: 'mothername', 
                        name: 'mothername',
                        visible: false, // Hidden column
                        searchable: true // Used for search functionality
                    },
    
                    
                    
 {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>  

Route
Route::get('/viewmember', [TotalmembersController::class, 'totalviewmembers'])->name('totalviewmembers');

